# How to add value against an Item in Joomla?

Tags: joomla-3.x, php

I would like to add some value against few items in Joomla 3.0. In the following code I would like to add value in the name and date item:

```
<?php 
$item = get_object_vars($this->item); 
$display_fields = array('name', 'email' 'date', 'amount');
?>
```

Like in date value, it will be showing date format like Y-m-d or in name item it will be showing some value like ABC. Right now in the above code, name and date value item are coming dynamically from other sources but I want to restrict it with my custom given name and date format. Need your help on this.

Comment: What are these items, where you call them and where are your custom values stored? Please add this information in your question.